# Search and edit null labels in the form

Tags: c#, foreach

I was trying to create a simple like to-do list. When I click the button, it should, from another form, search for the null labels and fill in first one with the text which is written in the text box. This what I have reached so far but it doesn't work at all:

```
Form1 f = new Form1();  
public void writetext()
{
    foreach (Control x in f.Controls)
    {
        if (x is Label)
        {
               if (((Label)x).Text == "")
            {
                ((Label)x).Text = textBox1.Text;
            }                          
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: but.. what have you tried? I don't see here any logic regarding **it searches for the null labels and fill and first one with the text which is written in the text box**

Comment: @tym32167 sorry , i posted it now

Comment: I'm assuming you're using WinForms. Change the tag if I guessed wrong. Note that C# can be used for many UI technologies which have forms and controls.

Comment: ok, now can you clarify, what exactly your problem about? What in yout code didnt work?

Comment: the code that i just posted doesn't work how can i make it work thats my question i cleared that i want the code to search null or empty labels and set the first null label to specific value which textbox1.text and then break

Comment: @OmarAlaa What is the problem?
1. You are getting an exception. If yes, which line?
2. Code gives no exception yet no desired output. In this case, debug and check if null labels exists in your code and they are detected. If label lbl = null, you code will definitely fail but if label is defined and initialized but text is empty then your code should work.

Comment: @AmeyKamat no i don't get any exception i click the button and nothing happens and there is empty a lot of empty labels in the form

Comment: The code you posted is making a new Form1, which is not the same instance as the one you are seeing on the screen.  You need to reference the existing Form1 you created.

Comment: @LarsTech you mean like making it the base class ?

Comment: I don't know what that means.  It's unclear from your code what are the forms you are displaying on the screen.  The only hint we have is that there are two forms on the screen.  On the posted code, you create a new Form1, but you never Show it.  And I'm guessing you don't want to, since it's probably already on the screen.  My guess is that you need to write it as `public void writetext(Form1 f)`  Remove that `Form1 f = new Form1();` line.